# Snackbar package in AndroidX

Tags: android, android-snackbar, androidx

When migrating a project or switching between branches which are and aren't migrated, Android Studio cannot build projects because it cannot find the `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar` package. Support/Design packages are removed but the [migration table](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor#migrate) does not list the correct new package for this component.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This took a long time to resolve, as until your project successfully builds, autocomplete will not function to lookup packages.

The correct package to use is:

```
com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
```

It is also important to remember to change this on the XML tags as well as the imports if the migration has not worked successfully.

Comment: do I have no other solution than to implement material into my app?

Answer (score 8):

Old build artifact `com.android.support:design` now solves in `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` for AndroidX build artifact.

Comment: For anyone searching: Currently the lastest stable is "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0".

Answer (score 7):

Add `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"` to  your app-level `build.gradle`.

Also, ensure that your project is set up to migrate old packages to Androidx by including this in your `gradle.properties` file:

`android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true`

Answer (score 2):

Import

```
com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
```

instead of

```
android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
```

if you shifted to androidx and AS couldn't find the package anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Updating to Anko version 0.10.8 will resolve this, it will tell you that snackbar(view, int) is now deprecated, instead of it you will use view.snackbar(int: Message)