# Can not resolve symbol annotation design ActivityCompat v7

Tags: java, android

I am working on a face recognition app using google API. But android studio says symbol not found.

Here is my activity. All four of them don't work.

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

My build.gradle(module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ece.course.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    productFlavors{
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
}
```

My build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am new to android and confused. I cleaned the project and rebuild it several times. Invalidate cache and restart several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers.

As it turns out, during project setup time I used the "basic activity" as a template for fast setup. But I later realized in the "basic activity" in newer version of Android Studio uses AndroidX instead of Android Suppor library. And all my code is based on the legacy android library.

In the file `gradle.properties` file(located in the base directory of your project same as gradlew), change

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

to

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

If you have all the dependency right and rebuild and cleared cache several times, still the android support library doesn't work. And if you have a newer version of android studio. It's possible that `gradle.properties` are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Because you have to migrate your project into the androidx.

You are using **compileSdkVersion 28**

Steps to migrate

1. Add the following properties to `gradle.properties`

   > android.useAndroidX=true
   >
   > android.enableJetifier=true

   2. From the menu bar: `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX…`

[Here](https://medium.com/@begalesagar/migrate-an-existing-project-to-androidx-from-support-libraries-adbac897089b) is the reference for whole process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ActivityCompat works. But Snackbar NonNull and AppCompatActivity still don't work.

Comment: Please make sure imports contains androidx instead of android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Migrate your project to androidx

```
Refactor > Migrate to Androidx
```

Another thing to remember is to check all your packages are correct in gradle. The Snackbar package for androidx is:

```
com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
```

Answered here:
[Snackbar package in AndroidX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593300/snackbar-package-in-androidx)

For Androidx artifact mapping. Take a look at the Android Developer API here:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

Sample:
[Artifact Mapping Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Z6A.png)